# List User by use role with count of posts they are assigned to

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I want to show a list of users by role with a count of how many posts they are assigned to. I use an ACF user field to assign posts to users, here is what I have so far, not sure if I am headed in the right direction.

```
$args_user_role = array(
    'role'    => 'um_pds-project-manager',
    'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
);
$users = get_users( $args_user_role );

$args_projects = array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'project',
  'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'   => 'status',
        'value' => '1'
    ),
          array(
        'key' => 'pds_project_manager',
        'value' => $users,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
  )
);
$posts = get_posts($args_projects);
$pm_count = count($posts);//this is the total number of posts
```

Comment: I'd like to try help but might need a little more info. What type of field are you using using to assign posts? Repeater with post object or ID in the user profile? I'm just not quite sure why you are using get_posts at all if you are just looking to list users.

Comment: Each post has a user field created with ACF, the user field returns a User array. The field allows multiple users to be selected. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/user/ I use this field to control which of my users can see which posts and need to provide a count that shows how many posts each user is assigned to (appears in that user field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you. I have a repeater field set up like this:

[image]

And the return value of the sub field is set to a user array:

[image]

Then loop through the post and repeater and add usernames, post ids, count and anything else you like to an array ($user_arr):

```
foreach($posts as $post):
    if ( have_rows('user_repeater') ) :
        while( have_rows('user_repeater') ) : the_row();
            $user_arr = get_sub_field('user');
            $arr[$user_arr['user_nicename']]['post_ids'][] =  $post->ID;
            $arr[$user_arr['user_nicename']]['post_count']++;
        endwhile;
    endif;
endforeach;
```

My array looks like this, you can use this to create your list:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about approaching from this stand point, something like this should work.